# CS106a Checkerboard optimization

Tags: java, graphics

I'm learning Java out of The Art & Science of Java by Roberts (Stanford's CS106a text). I'm using NetBeans as my IDE.

Chapter 4, exercise 14 asks you to expand on a Checkerboard program introduced earlier. Specifically, it asks you to center the checkerboard and draw a set of red & white checks corresponding to the initial state of the game.

I've accomplished as much as requested, but have two issues-

1. The board is not completely centered in the window. It is closer to the left side of the window than the right side. I am not sure how to center it more. Am I doing this right? Is there a setting in NetBeans I can/should change?
2. The checkers are supposed to take up a large portion of the tiles they sit on. I assigned the size of my checkers to be dependent on the size of tiles so that the setup would be simple and proportionate. Is there a better way to do this to make the checkers bigger?

   ```
   import acm.graphics.*;
   import acm.program.*;
   import java.awt.*;

   public class Checkerboard extends GraphicsProgram{

   public void run(){

   double sqSize = (double)getHeight() / N_ROWS;
   for (int i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < N_COLUMNS; j++){
           double x = ((j * sqSize) + (getWidth() / N_COLUMNS));  //centers square??
           double y = (i * sqSize);
           GRect sq = new GRect( x, y, sqSize, sqSize );
           sq.setFilled((i + j) % 2 != 0);
           sq.setFillColor(Color.GRAY);
           add(sq);

           double circleCoord = (sqSize * .33);
           double xx = ((j * sqSize) + (getWidth() / N_COLUMNS) + circleCoord);
           double yy = ((i * sqSize) + circleCoord);

           if((i + j) % 2 != 0 && i < 3 ){
               GOval red = new GOval( xx, yy, circleCoord, circleCoord);
               red.setFilled(true);
               red.setFillColor(Color.RED);
               add(red);

           } else if((i + j) % 2 != 0 && i > 4 ){
               GOval black = new GOval( xx, yy, circleCoord, circleCoord);
               black.setFilled(true);
               black.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
               add(black);
           }

        }
      }
   }
   private static final int N_ROWS = 8;
   private static final int N_COLUMNS = 8; 

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1. The center of the board should be in the center of the width, too. So we know that

The left edge of tile `N_COLUMNS/2` = `getWidth()/2` e.g. tile 4 in 0 indexing has its left edge in the center

And every tile left or right of that will have a movement of sqSize, so:

`double x = getWidth()/2 + (j-N_COLUMNS/2)*sqSize`

Comment: Thank you, this solution makes sense and helps a lot!